# What is phantom reference in java

Tags: java, reference

There are four type of references in Java: Strong, Soft, Weak, and phantom. Kindly elaborate where and how Java exactly use phantom reference.

EDIT :

I did read the javaDoc, as assylias posted below. the section says an object is phantom rechable if it has been finalized and some phantom refernce refers to it. I dint quite get that statement.

What is the use of phantom and in which cases shall we use it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: I typed that word on google, and it gave me this link: - [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) - MORAL -- Be friend with google..

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80690/phantom-referenced-objects

Comment: @Raedwald, i dont want anyone to do my homework for me. I was seeking some help.
I did read the javaDoc, as assylias posted below. 
the section says an object is phantom rechable if it has been finalized, and some phantom refernce refers to it. 
I dint quite get that statement. 
I should have added that in my description
and also i dint get the use of phantom , why it is used. that is why i asked where it is used in my question

Comment: @RohitJain I did read that documentation, but dint quite get the concept and usage of phantom. that is why the question. I should have added all that description in my question

Comment: @Tichodroma Yes, I did read through java doc, I`ll take care, that if i ask question, I do add my research background so people don't take it as if I am asking them to do my homework

Comment: @MukulGoel.. Its no problem.. But for future, while asking question, remember to tell what you already know, what you have already done.. This will prevent us from trying the same thing again..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Java's Reference classes: SoftReference, WeakReference, and PhantomReference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329691/understanding-javas-reference-classes-softreference-weakreference-and-phanto)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How each type of reference works is described in the [`java.lang.ref` package javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html):

> Going from strongest to weakest, the different levels of reachability reflect the life cycle of an object. They are operationally defined as follows:
>
> - An object is strongly reachable if it can be reached by some thread without traversing any reference objects. A newly-created object is strongly reachable by the thread that created it.
> - An object is softly reachable if it is not strongly reachable but can be reached by traversing a soft reference.
> - An object is weakly reachable if it is neither strongly nor softly reachable but can be reached by traversing a weak reference. When the weak references to a weakly-reachable object are cleared, the object becomes eligible for finalization.
> - An object is phantom reachable if it is neither strongly, softly, nor weakly reachable, it has been finalized, and some phantom reference refers to it.
> - Finally, an object is unreachable, and therefore eligible for reclamation, when it is not reachable in any of the above ways.

There are a few posts on Stack OVerflow that give examples of how and when you might need a `PhantomReference`:

- [Have you ever used Phantom reference in any project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599069/have-you-ever-used-phantom-reference-in-any-project)
- [When to use phantom references in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826741/java-phantom-reference-when-we-using-it)

Comment: Thanks, but i did read that from javadoc. understood the strong,soft and weak. but dint quite get phantom. what exactly it is and where should I be using it.

Comment: @MukulGoel Ok that was not clear in your original question. This post answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826741/java-phantom-reference-when-we-using-it - short answer: it has little practical use and 99.9% of developers won't ever use that feature.

Comment: Yea, the original question was little too generic. Thanks. That link says what i was looking for.

Comment: @MukulGoel I have edited my post with a second link.

Comment: How do phantom references make sense then? Except perhaps for debugging the JVM how it is useful to delay collecting an object until the phantom reference is gone? Isn't this increasing likelyhood of an OOM. Also it seems there is no way to tell if particular object has been actually collected.

Comment: @akostadinov I have personally never used them - the 2 posts at the bottom of my answer give a few use cases.